# SQL (PLSQL), how to select distinct but with count > 1

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a table `INVOICE` with `ID_STUFF, STUFF_NAME, E_MAIL` columns. I need to find rows, that have the same ID_STUFF but different STUFF_NAME or E_MAIL.

```
select distinct g.id_stuff, g.staff_name, g.e_mail from invoice g
```

shows this:
[image]

But I don't need the rows that have the same values for the same `ID_STUFF`.

Comment: What is your expected output, based on the sample data you have shown us?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need the output like on the screenshot, but without lines with id_stuff = 1, 4, 6 because thier count is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want the original rows.  If so, I would recommend using `exists` *twice*:

```
select i.*
from invoice i
where exists (select 1
              from invoice i2
              where i2.id_stuff = i.id_stuff and
                    i2.staff_name <> i.staff_name
             ) or
     exists (select 1
             from invoice i2
             where i2.id_stuff = i.id_stuff and
                   i2.e_mail <> i.e_mail
            ) ;
```

The query can make use of indexes on `invoice(id_stuff, e_mail)` and `invoice(id_stuff, staff_name)` -- which would be a big performance win on a large table.

If you just want the `id_stuff`, then `group by` is a fine solution.  You can get the list of names and emails using `listagg()`:

```
select i.id_stuff,
       listagg(e_mail, ',') within group (order by e_mail),
       listagg(staff_name, ',') within group (order by staff_name)
from invoice i
group by i.id_stuff
having min(e_mail) <> max(e_email) or
       min(staff_name) <> max(staff_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists` to find similar records:

```
 select  g.id_stuff, g.staff_name, g.e_mail from invoice g
 where exists 
 (select 1 from invoice g1 where g1.id_stuff =g.id_stuff
  and ( g1.staff_name <> g.staff_name or g1.e_mail <> g.e_mail)
```